# Can't copy highlighted text from Tomboy to Thunderbird (or other apps)

Tags: tomboy

Not sure why but I can only copy text from Tomboy notes to Gedit and then re-highlight and copy in to the app I need the text in.

I am guessing this is a simple issue of config and not a real problem.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start up **Tomboy Notes**, Go to **Help>About**

This will tell you what version you are using. I'm using version 1.4.2 on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick AMD 64Bit and I can **highlight and right click to copy**, and I can **right click and paste** into any other program. I can also do a **CTRL C to copy** and **Ctrl V to paste** using keyboard shortcuts with no problems.

I have tested this on a Netbook Acer One Inspire running Ubuntu 10.04 i32bit. On an HP Pavillion with Ubuntu 10.10 i32bit, and on a Compaq Presario CQ62 running 10.10 64 bit amd version. Tested on Evolution mail, Thunderbird, LibreOffice Writer, OpenOffice Writer, Gedit. No problems.

**Unfortunately**, the **formatting is lost** with **Tomboy** and **Gnote** when pasting to other applications. (Gnote is the same program but ported to C+++ and a bit faster.)

**SOLUTION:** You could however, **export** your note as an **HTML** file, Save it to your desktop or folder, then open it with **Firefox**, copy and paste to any application and this will preserve the formatting of the original note.

To do this **open a note with Tomboy**, click on the **tool icon** (*gear looking icon*), and select **Export to HTML**.

You can also go to **Edit>Preferences>Add-ins**.
There are many **addins** for this program. The only thing that is **very cryptic** is that you need to click on the **tool icon** on an open note to see the **print menu**.

**This is important in case you need to Back up your notes.**

Your notes are just a simple **xml** format files. They are kept in a **hidden folder** under your **home folder**. ***In Ubuntu Hidden folders start with a period. To see them you need to enable it under the View Menu or do CTRL H***. Once you know this, it is very easy to backup your notes. :-)

.local/share/tomboy

Click **Places**, Click **Home Folder**, Click **View**, Click **Show Hidden Files**, double click **.local** folder, double click **share** folder, double click **tomboy** folder.

Just copy your tomboy folder and paste a copy of it for safe keeping.

**You can also use other apps to see your notes.**
Navigate to the hidden folder .local/share/tomboy
Right click on a note, select open with other application, **REMEBER TO REMOVE the check-mark that says to, "Remember this application for "application/x-note type" files**. You can choose, a web browser, LibreOffice Writer, Gedit etc. to see the note, with fancy xml tags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running Tomboy 1.4.2 on Ubuntu 10.10 32bit. Unfortunately I could not use the rest of your advise to fix my problem. Any ideas why I can only copy in to certain other apps and not all of them?

Comment: After further investigating this issue it seems that Thunderbird didn't want to paste the text with the formatting that Tomboy had made. In Thunderbird I went to Edit>Paste Without Formatting and it copied the text without the hyperlinks/bolding that were in the Tomboy note.

Comment: I have spruced up my original answer. Maybe try re-installing Tomboy, back-up your notes, then go to Ubuntu Software centre, and remove Tomboy,then re-install it.

Comment: Check your software Sources, make sure you are getting your updates from the Main Server. I have had issues in the past, with weird errors, and they have disappeared once I set it to Main Server ie. Canonical. I know that when Ubuntu gets installed it chooses the servers that are closer to where one lives.